# C# naming and styling

Tags: c#

I've been reading the .net framework source and found this in the [stack implementation](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/stack.cs):

```
while(i < _size) {
    objArray[i] = _array[_size-i-1];
    i++;
}
```

I want to know why there are "_" (underscore) symbols and why the brace is not on a separate line?

It is not "C# style", is it?

Comment: `_` prefix is usually used to refers to a member of a class

Comment: There's a thread talking about the coding standards over on [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/7629/recommended-net-c-coding-standards)

Comment: @Thomas got it, thanks

Comment: @AlG thanks for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Styles are fluid, and change between companies, times, and employees, unless strictly enforced.

the `_` is probably a shorthand for `m_` that used to indicate a private member.
As long as your consistent with your style, it shouldn't really matter.

Have a look at [hungarian notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation). Even though not very relevant these days in many languages (being strongly typed, and having intellisense), it was useful back in the day :)

Answer (score 1):

We use this at my work to denote class level variables - that is pretty commonplace, however Visual Studio intellisense gives you this indicator. If you venture as far as using StyleCop, you have to actively allow this notation, as it's default rules prefer this. notation.

Answer (score 1):

Most people tend to use this style (as it is implement in Resharper). And this kind of naming is usually given to `private readonly` members.